# How to test a date is later/greater than another in jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I understand that JavaScript allows for basic comparison between dates e.g.,

```
const dateOne = new Date();
const dateTwo = new Date();

return dateTwo > dateOne;
```

I can see there is a `.toBeGreaterThan()` expectation in Jest, but this is only for numbers or big ints. Is there something available for dates to compare one is later than another?

Comment: calling .getTime() on a Date object returns the number of milliseconds.

Comment: You might do `(+dateOne).toBeGreaterThan(+dateTwo)` as `+` coerces Date to milliseconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `date.getTime()`, that'll return the date in unix milliseconds.